# Замена символов в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть таблица с данными, которую я загружаю в классификатор. Далее, классификатор кодирует данные и получить их можно в виде словаря. Мне нужно закодированные значения поставить на места оригинальных ([пример](https://sun9-37.userapi.com/c857616/v857616214/ae29c/BuR6RcnEqss.jpg) для наглядности). Первое, что приходит на ум, использовать `replace` Pandas. Я попробовал его на маленьком объеме данных (20 строк на 280 столбцов) всё посчиталось за 15 секунд, а вот на большом объеме (120 000 строк на 280 столбцов) уже четыре дня считается. Подозреваю, что подход с поиском и заменой не очень подходит тут.

Как можно упростить и ускорить замену?

Код замены:

```py
    for key, value in xxx.items(): 
    lime_df.replace(value, key, inplace = True)
```

Где: `xxx` - словарь, `lime_df` изначальные данные.

P.S: Может быть есть вариант ускорить замену с помощью GPU? В распоряжении есть Tesla k80.

Comment: Для того чтобы вам помочь надо чётко понимать что вы хотите сделать. Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Замена нужна в одном столбце или в 280?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример данных:

```
strings = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(strings, size=(120000, 280)))
```

---

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
        0    1    2    3    4    ...  275  276  277  278  279
0       bbb  ddd  aaa  ccc  aaa  ...  bbb  aaa  aaa  bbb  aaa
1       ddd  aaa  aaa  bbb  ddd  ...  bbb  bbb  ccc  ccc  ddd
2       bbb  aaa  ddd  ccc  bbb  ...  ccc  ddd  aaa  aaa  bbb
3       ccc  ccc  ddd  ccc  bbb  ...  bbb  bbb  bbb  aaa  bbb
4       bbb  ccc  aaa  ccc  bbb  ...  bbb  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc
...     ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
119995  bbb  aaa  ccc  aaa  ddd  ...  bbb  bbb  ddd  ccc  ccc
119996  ccc  bbb  aaa  ddd  aaa  ...  aaa  ccc  ddd  ccc  bbb
119997  aaa  ddd  ddd  bbb  bbb  ...  ddd  aaa  bbb  aaa  ddd
119998  bbb  aaa  ddd  ddd  ddd  ...  ccc  ddd  ddd  aaa  aaa
119999  bbb  ccc  aaa  bbb  ddd  ...  bbb  ccc  ddd  aaa  ccc

[120000 rows x 280 columns]

In [23]: df.shape
Out[23]: (120000, 280)
```

Решение:

```
In [27]: mapping = {"aaa":1, "bbb":2, "ccc":3, "ddd":4}

In [28]: %%timeit -n 1
    ...: res = df.replace(mapping)
    ...:
    ...:
33.2 s ± 5.81 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
In [34]: res
Out[34]:
        0    1    2    3    4    ...  275  276  277  278  279
0         2    4    1    3    1  ...    2    1    1    2    1
1         4    1    1    2    4  ...    2    2    3    3    4
2         2    1    4    3    2  ...    3    4    1    1    2
3         3    3    4    3    2  ...    2    2    2    1    2
4         2    3    1    3    2  ...    2    3    3    3    3
...     ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
119995    2    1    3    1    4  ...    2    2    4    3    3
119996    3    2    1    4    1  ...    1    3    4    3    2
119997    1    4    4    2    2  ...    4    1    2    1    4
119998    2    1    4    4    4  ...    3    4    4    1    1
119999    2    3    1    2    4  ...    2    3    4    1    3

[120000 rows x 280 columns]
```

**Итог:** заменили 33.6 млн. значений за 33.2 секунды на 3-х летнем ноуте.

Comment: У меня словарь выглядит вот так `{-5.486750964678322e-08: '2',
 1.187718366754473e-17: '3',
 -7.059511863971579e-10: '10',
 -3.0349327687745536e+16: '18',
 -8.017016298890468e-18: '15',
 107.15808868408203: '1',
 -8.300757059487296e-08: '5',
 -2.1828310439085026e+32: '13',
 -1.3752891451707128e+38: '8',
 5.882867218031023e-22: '14',
 -1.0941715971078361e+23: '17',
 -8.360684200807262e-18: '11',
 -1.0765597196911002e+36: '4',
 -1.5831559552949374e+38: '7',
 -1.5324417530020214e-27: '9', }` и присваивание не происходит. Я так понимаю, что нужно поменять местами значение и ключ?

Comment: @МаксимФрейд, ну да...

Comment: Кстати, а какой смысл иметь значения стремящиеся к нулю или к +- бесконечности в качестве __ключей__ словаря?

Comment: Так Catboost кодирует их для классификации

Comment: Время действительно уменьшилось, только спустя 23 минуты вышла ошибка "TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'"

Comment: @МаксимФрейд, я вам уже несколько раз в комментариях приводил ссылки на: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/). Без __воспроизводимого__ примера данных - и вы и я теряем время впустую :(

Comment: Вы не смотрели случайно то, что я скидывал? :)

Comment: @МаксимФрейд, Если не забуду, то попробую посмотреть через неделю, когда вернусь из отпуска. :)

Comment: Понял, хорошего отпуска!